# Bootstrap and scrollTo.js navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I am a novice front-ender, and I have an incomprehensible problem. On my page, when you click on the links from the top menu, it scrolls down to the desired block. However, the link is not marked active unless the user scrolls the page a few pixels down. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?
Here's the html:

```
            <nav class="menu">
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                     <li><a data-action="scrollTo" href="#content" class="hover">Download</a></li>
                     <li><a data-action="scrollTo" href="#productfeatures">Product Features</a></li>
                     <li><a data-action="scrollTo" href="#howitlooklike">How it look like</a></li>
                     <li><a data-action="scrollTo" href="#mobile">Mobile Version</a></li>
                     <li><a data-action="scrollTo" href="#footer">Contacts</a></li>     
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav><!-- Nav End-->
```

If you refresh the page and scroll up - an active link would appear.

all code you can see [here](http://tourlly.com/new/)

Comment: i am not getting active when I clicked the link or scroll down.

Comment: and that is the problem, you need to scroll little bit down, after click

Comment: if you make a fiddle it would be easy to explain you have to manually get the click events of the <a> tags and remove class hover from all and add class hover to the present selected anchor

Comment: @КонстантинРусанов vinod has a point. We can put a script to alter it. I am not familiar with the plugin but I am guessing maybe it has something to do with positioning. So I don't know what to give you an answer `A script just to make your menu correct` or `your plugin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap then why not use 'ScrollSpy' JS component of it?

Its easy to use and allows to set offset from top of window, which is the root problem with your site right now. Its activating based on position from top while you are having fixed navigation.

You can use 'ScrollSpy' and set offset little higher than your NAV elements height. Also, theres 'activate' event which fires everytime new nav link is activated. So that should do the trick for you.

Here's the link: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: ScrollSpy - thank you, your method worked, but there was another problem - when you click on the link screen is moved to the desired location, but the menu covers the section heading and does not look good. How to make the menu was slightly above the title of each section?

Comment: @Константин, Add **data-offset** attribute on BODY tag for offset from top. I just tried with 60 on your site and it looks fine. So you can add `data-offset="60"` to BODY tag, increase if you want more.